# how to separate a split array $input back into the 2 separate value in php

Tags: php, split

My current `$input` array is as follows `Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 250 [2] => 18|1.0 [3] => 70 [4] => 9.0 )`

How can I grab the split values  in `$input[2]` above without causing `Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in ....` 
error  The error is because it doesn't know which number to select due to the split |. is there a way to say `number before split` then `number after split` as I need to now reference the values separately to calculate.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you store in `$input[2]` not string but result of [bitwise operation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) `| (OR)` = number `19`. So when you want to perform any mathematical action on that variable you will get always number 19.

It's impossible to revert `bitwise OR` operation.

```
$number = 18 | 1.0;
$string_number = "18|1.0";

var_dump($number); // int(19)
var_dump($string_number); //string(6) "18|1.0"

$string_number_array = explode('|', $string_number);

var_dump($string_number_array[0]); // string(2) "18"
var_dump($string_number_array[1]); // string(3) "1.0"
var_dump((int)$string_number_array[0]); // double(18)
var_dump((double)$string_number_array[1]); // double(1)
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean sorry. that particular sting is made up when a certain option is selected in the drop-down. Basically, When someone selects an option in the drop-down I needed it to output the 2 numbers into a string to calculate (these numbers aren't actually calculated together, but they are needed separately for the rest of the equation, Now im being told It needs to be another way.  This has me so confused

Comment: Answer is in the snippet. Have you run it to check how behave value `18|1.0` as number? You must split this string into array and then get first or second number.

Comment: Ok, so i added that to the file,  refreshed and it gave the string `int(19) string(6) "18|1.0" string(2) "18" string(3) "1.0" int(18) float(1)`

However when i change a value, the array updates, but the string does not `Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 250 [2] => 72|0.0 [3] => 70 [4] => 0.0 )`

Comment: If `$input[2] = "18|1.0"` then first value is `explode('|', $string_number)[0]` and second value is `explode('|', $string_number)[1]`

Comment: still scratching my head over this,  im getting no error.  couold you confirm i have placed these correctly `mysqli_close($link);
$string_number = $input[2];
var_dump($string_number); //string(6) "18|1.0"
$nicbase = explode('|', $string_number)[0];
$nicvg = explode('|', $string_number)[1];`

Comment: it now looks like this on the page `string(6) "18|0.4" 0175.00ml or 220.50g)`  the 175.00ml or 220.50g is what should show as its a hint which should show after the calulations,  the variable doesnt seem to have seperated but im not sure how to check, does it matter that one number is 2 numbers `18` and the other is a decimal`0.4`?

Comment: You have `$nicbase = 18` and $nicvg = 1.0`. Isn't the result you wanted to achieve? You can do the same with `"18|0.4"` But I have no idea what is 0175.00ml or 220.50g.

Comment: It's working, I re-read your advice and realised i'd left it dumping the string to the page,  got the calculations lined up ad its working great 

Thank you for your help

Comment: i have no idea how to accept sorry